# How to print all the lines that's first word is the first word of a file?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a text file `sort.txt`, which has content something like this:

```
2 Jack
2 Naomi
2 Tina
1 John
1 Tyler
```

I want to print out all the lines that begin with `2`, but the problem is the number might not always be `2`, it can be any number. I just want to print all the lines who's first word is the same as the first line. So if the first word was `3`, print out all the lines that start with `3`. I tried doing this, but it didn't work:

```
firstWord=awk '{print $1;}'
egrep "^$firstWord" sort.txt
```

Comment: What about a line (for the example) that is: `22Jeff`, or `22 Jeff`?

Comment: it would never have lines with that, because i already created sort.txt to have a space between all numbers

Comment: Ok; I wanted to double-check, because your grep statement allows for "anything" following the "firstWord" -- at least, that's the direction it was going. Wanted to make sure the Answers followed what you intended. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty trivial with `awk`. Get the first word of first line in a variable and then for the subsequent lines, use that variable to match the first word and print only those lines

```
awk 'NR == 1 { fw = $1 } $1 == fw' sort.txt
```

The construct `NR == 1` gets only the first line of the input file and there is no special de-limiters defined in each line (white-space de-limited), the first field is accessed by `$1` and stored into `fw`. The later condition `$1 == fw` evaluates each lines and returns true only if the condition is satisfied, thereby printing the line.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk 'NR == 1 { word=$1 } { if (match($0, "^"word) > 0) print }' < sort.txt
```

On the first line `NR == 1`, assign the "word" value to be the first word from the line.

On any line, if the line matches the variable `word` at the beginning of the line, print it.

Comment: I've reworked the awk statement to avoid the double-printing, and also more closely align with the "grep ^pattern" example.